# How to read highspeed Serial-data using Python?

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I am working on a project to display sensor data on Python GUI. Sensor data is coming at a rate of `2kHz` on serial port using Arduino. I was using pyserial (using readline()) to read the sensor data on my laptop. After hours of debugging I found that python was able to read around 400 samples/sec i.e. reading frequency is around `400Hz`.

Is there any way to read the serial data at higher rate with the help of python?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you configured a correct baudrate? https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html#opening-serial-ports

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sensor is designed to transmit 2kHz data and is doing so properly, my guess is that the time your Python code is taking to read a data sample, process the data, update a plot, etc is the limiting factor. Are you reading and processing samples one at a time?  Is there a smart way to read all of the available in a big chunk reducing the number of individual read/process steps?

Are you plotting the data in "real time"? If so, plot updates are slow.